# nfsstat authrefrsh almost equal to calls

Tags: networking, performance, nfs

I mounted a dir from my server through nfs (v3) on my LAN and if I run nfsstat I get

```
# nfsstat -rc
Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
2527772    0          2527782
```

Is this something that is going to affect performance?

My mount options in fstab are just

```
noauto,relatime,noexec
```

And the export file is using

```
(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Comment: Similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13557/69080